# How to use only two channels for gray scale images in Convolutional neural network and autoencoders not 3 channels RGB

Tags: python, deep-learning, autoencoder

I have a gray scale images (ultrasound) and i want to train them using CNN and autoencoders but i have issue with number of channels which is 3 by default , when i use the 3 channels an error reported , how can i use only 2 channels.

```
ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 2 and 3 for 'loss_mse/sub' (op: 'Sub') with input shapes: [?,128,128,2], [?,128,128,3].
```

Comment: you have to modify the network architecture. You could also double a channel and provide the network with redundant information. Of course, this would not work on a pretrained network.

What network are you using? Are you using pytorch? tensorflow? Can you provide an example of your network definition ?

Comment: I am using tensorflow, which part of code should i modify please?